# Will apt upgrade, ran with yes flag, reboot if needed?

Tags: apt, upgrade

For example, if I run `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` if there is a package that requires a restart to upgrade, will the yes flag cause the system to reboot after the command finishes upgrading everything? Or, will it still require a manual reboot?

OS and Software:

- Debian Buster 10 -> kernel version 4.19 on a Raspbian HW
- `apt` 1.8.2 (`armhf`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, `apt` on its own won’t reboot.

You can check whether the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists after running `apt` to see if a reboot is required. If you use `unattended-upgrades`, you can configure that to reboot for you.

Comment: If the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists, then it's necessary to reboot? Is it normal that the file is empty?

Comment: @A.L it means that a package has requested that the system be rebooted; whether a reboot is *necessary* is up to the system administrator. Typical occurrences involve kernel upgrades: the kernel upgrade isn’t effective until the system has been rebooted (ignoring live kernel patching techniques). The file is supposed to be empty, yes.

Answer (score 5):

No, `apt-get` will not reboot by itself, but if you want your system to reboot automatically after an update if necessary then add `[ -e /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot` to your command:

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade; [ -e /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to do scripting, but this does save me some time.